# Query Setup Error when Testing Endpoint in AWS DMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I'm getting the following error when trying to test a target connection to a Redshift db using AWS DMS tool:

```
Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Query setup error
```

The redshift cluster is in the same VPC, subnet group & security group as the replication instance. The security group allows all traffic inbound from itself. Is there a location I can get full logs for the endpoint test, or more details about this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query setup error is not a network error - but rather relates to errors coming from SQL engine itself. In my case AWS support was able to look up the logs. In there was an error line about the database name being wrong.